# How to select columns in Hive SQL with the same prefix (beginning) or suffix (ending) or key word in the middle (including)

Tags: regex, hive, hive-query

EDIT 1: Note, I know some of us will question why not list different parts of information in different attributes, so that I will have a relational database to query. The real case is not like the example I am listing below, the variable names are just used here for convenience.

EDIT 2: To reduce the confusion of database design, I change the variable names in the example.

In Hive query, I am looking for a way to select columns with the same prefix, or the same suffix, or including the same key word in the middle of the variable names from the same table.

Here is an example: I have a list of variables like this:

```
a_A_1, a_A_2, a_B_1, a_B_2,
b_A_1, b_A_2, b_B_1, b_B_2
```

**Exercise 1**
I want to select all the attributes *starting with 'a'*.

**Exercise 2**
I want to select all the attributes *ending with '1'*.

**Exercise 3**
I want to select all the attributes *including 'B'*.

Much thanks in advance!

Comment: I would like to point out that that's a poor database design. Hive allows nested data types and arrays. For example, a region struct holds an array of items, and each year should be its own row and one column

Comment: @cricket_007 Please see note 1 and 2. The variable names are just made up for convenience. It is not what I have in the database. LOL.

Comment: @cricket_007 FYI, the answer is posted below. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Luckily [I found a way to do so](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Select#LanguageManualSelect-REGEXColumnSpecification)  and I hope it can benefit many others who are looking for the same answer.

First of all, you need to run this setting in your Hive environment:

```
set hive.support.quoted.identifiers=none;
```

See solutions below

**Exercise 1**

```
select `a.*` from test_table;
```

**Exercise 2**

```
select `.*1$` from test_table;
```

**Exercise 3**

```
select `.*B.*` from test_table;
```

Comment: Curious - where did you find this answer?

Comment: @cricket_007 Apache Hive Confluence Site: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Select#LanguageManualSelect-REGEXColumnSpecification

Comment: @cricket_007 could you undo the down vote, if you voted it? I already explained my old naming for the attributes and changed it to a less confusing name. Thanks.

Comment: @cricket_007 how did you put the back kick in the answer post? good job... and thanks.

Comment: If you look at the revisions, you can select side by side markdown

Comment: @cricket_007. Cool. Thanks!